# consolidating database query and grouping values into arrays

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql

I have the following postsql database output:

```
 id    | tau | wspd |    sector     |      radius       
 ------+-----+------+---------------+-------------------
 49272 |   0 |   34 | {NE,SE,SW,NW} | {150,125,80,130}
 49272 |   0 |   50 | {NE,SE,SW,NW} | {60,30,35,55}
 49272 |   3 |   34 | {NE,SE,SW,NW} | {150,125,80,130}
 49272 |   3 |   50 | {NE,SE,SW,NW} | {60,30,35,55}
 49272 |  12 |   34 | {NE,SE,SW,NW} | {140,110,70,120}
 49272 |  12 |   50 | {NE,SE,SW,NW} | {45,40,35,35}
 49272 |  24 |   34 |{NE,SE,SW,NW}  | {160,120,80,00}
```

from running the following statement:

```
select id, tau, wspd, sector, radius 
from data_base 
where id = 49272;
```

How can I tweak this query to get the following output?

```
  id    |  tau  |  wspd   |  sector                    |  radius
  ------+-------+---------+----------------------------+-------------------------------
  49272 |  0    |  {34,50}|{NE,SE,SW,NW},{NE,SE,SW,NW} | {150,125,80,130},{60,30,35,55}
  49272 |  3    |  {34,50}|{NE,SE,SW,NW},{NE,SE,SW,NW} | {150,125,80,130},{60,30,35,55}
  49272 |  12   |  {34,50}|{NE,SE,SW,NW},{NE,SE,SW,NW} | {140,110,70,120},{45,40,35,35}
  49272 |  24   |  {34}   |{NE,SE,SW,NW}               | {160,120,80,00}
```

where the `wspd, sector` and `radius` values are grouped together into arrays based on a single tau?

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` and aggregate with `array_agg`. Aggregated results are cast to text only in order to be like the ones in the question. It might be a good idea to aggregate using `json_agg` w/o cast too.

```
with t as
(
  -- whatever query that produces your dataset
  select id,tau,wspd,sector,radius 
  from data_base where id=49272
)
select id, tau,
       array_agg(wspd)::text wspd,
       array_agg(sector)::text sector,
       array_agg(radius)::text radius
from t group by id, tau;
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ouaivXQRLUTwdppRFvfQSx/2).